# Group By using Eloquent (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH8H1.png)The Problem occur when I add group by in my query...

```
Form::select('*')->groupBy('serial_num')->orderBy('id')->Paginate(10);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'database.form.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `form` group
>   by `serial_num` limit 10 offset 0)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query?  Can you show us sample input and output data?  The query you wrote does not make sense, but then again perhaps it is not what you are intending to do.

Comment: Do you have any model named `Form`?

Comment: Yes I have a Model name. I want to list all records but i want to group by those records which have same serial number...

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Laravel. You‘re selecting non-aggregated columns (*) in combination with grouping.

You have two options here

1. use aggregation (Min, Max, Avg, Group_concat) on each column you‘re selecting and not grouping by
2. disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on the MySQL server

More detailed explanation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Edit:
Apparently Laravel can set MySQL modes on the fly as well.

As mentioned in the comments, you can disable strict mode in the Laravel database settings, Laravel then should set the MySQL server mode accordingly, I don’t find up-to-date documentation for this tho

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php#L59

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/

make sure you clear any config cache after changing the setting

Answer (score 1):

Go to config\database.php

Set

```
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => false
```

after you saved, run this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: I changed strict to false but again the same problem occurred, so i changed strict to true

Comment: Did you clear cache after you change?

Comment: Yes I cleared cache: php artisan config:cache, php artisan cache:clear and also I run php artisan optimize, but it did not worked...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i cleared the cache and i restarted my server(xampp and laravel) and group by worked...

Answer (score 1):

If you could handle the Pagination by yourself, then you could obtain the results and then implement [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) on the collection.

```
$forms = Form::orderBy('id')->get()->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['serial_num'];
});
```